# What does Tarot card size mean

Tags: playing-cards, tarot

What does tarot card size mean?

Answer (score 5):

If you're asking for dimensions, what I found is Mayday sleeves for *french tarot* cards listing size as **61x112mm**

[image: Mayday Sleeves for french tarot cards]

And FFG "tarot sized" sleeves are **70x120mm**

[image: FFG Tarot Sized sleeves]

Answer (score 2):

Tarot is played with 78 cards and at the beginning of the game a player's hand is quite big (18 cards for a 4-player game ; 15 for a 5-player game and 24 for a 3-player game).
With an ordinary format (Poker or Bridge), it would be difficult to hold them, so Tarot cards are longer and narrower.

The measurements I found are 60mmx120mm.

More info (in French) [on the wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarot_nouveau#Format)